# Advice Requested on SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to take an existing query that I received help with and expand upon it. The query is:

```
,COUNT (DISTINCT 
  (CASE 
    WHEN EventDate between DATEADD(day, -56, @STARTDATE) AND DATEADD(day, -29, @STARTDATE) THEN EventId 
  END)
) PrevMonth
```

I now need to expand upon this to add some conditions. Some explanation of those conditions are below:

For each EventId (customer encounter) we have a Complexity rating (numeric value). Each EventId will have multiple rows covering the lifecycle of the encounter, contract.

Modify the existing criteria to return a distinct count of EventId's where the lowest complexity value is returned for that EventId.

So for a specified date range, grouping by EventId's, I need to be able to get a count based on the lowest complexity count. This should allow me to know how EventId's (customer encounters), where the lowest complexity level was a specific value.

I know I can use the MIN function to return the lowest value from all of the encounters under a single EventId.

I am just confused on how to put this together to get the answer I want. Suggestions would be appreciated.

The full query is:

```
Declare @temp table(YTD_Previous float, YTD_Current float, TwentyEightDays float, FiftySixDays float)

insert into @temp

SELECT
 COUNT (DISTINCT (CASE when EventDate between DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0,DATEADD(YEAR,-1, @STARTDATE)), 0) and DATEADD(Year,-1,@STARTDATE) then EventId END)) YTD_Previous
,COUNT (DISTINCT (CASE when EventDate between DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0,DATEADD(YEAR,-0, @STARTDATE)), 0)and DATEADD(Year,-0,@STARTDATE) then EventId END)) YTD_Current
,COUNT (DISTINCT (CASE when EventDate between DATEADD(YEAR,-0,DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), -28)) and DATEADD(Year,-0,@STARTDATE) then EventId END)) TwentyEightDays
,COUNT (DISTINCT (CASE WHEN EventDate between DATEADD(day, -56, @STARTDATE) AND DATEADD(day, -29, @STARTDATE) THEN EventId END)) FiftySixDays

FROM Transaction

WHERE Region IN (@Region)

SELECT 
     YTD_Current
    , YTD_Previous
    , case when (YTD_Previous - YTD_Current) = 0 then 0 when YTD_Previous = 0 then YTD_Current else (YTD_Current - YTD_Previous) / YTD_Previous end YTD_Chg        
        , TwentyEightDays
        , FiftySixDays
        , Case when (FiftySixDays - TwentyEightDays) = 0 then 0 when FiftySixDays = 0 then TwentyEightDays else (TwentyEightDays - FiftySixDays) / FiftySixDays end WEEK_Chg 

FROM @temp
```

[image]

Comment: we'd really need to see the rest of the query, some sample data, and the expected result of the query (based on that sample data). That would give context to your explanation.

Comment: Also, is this for SQL Server? If so, please tag it appropriately then people know what syntax to use for their answers

Comment: You have shown an expression, not a query.

Comment: This is a SQL query building a dataset for Report Builder. 

It was tagged as SQL, at least it shows that on my screen.

Comment: Yes but SQL could be MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, SQLite, or half a dozen others. So which product are you using, exactly? If you'd hovered over the "sql" tag and read the description you would see that it mentions that you need to add an additional tag for your DBMS :-) . Also we still need sample data and expected results, as previous mentioned. It's very hard to write a correct query (at least anything more than a totally trivial one) when you can't see the data you're working with. Thanks

Comment: The full query has been added above. The end result was a single row of values wtih a count of YTD_Current, YTD_Previous, FiftySixDays, TwentyEightDays, and then a column for the diff between the YTD values and a column for 28 to 56 values.

Comment: by "expected result" we generally mean _some actual data_, not a description of what the fields are called - we can already see that from the code. The expected result should show the data which would be output by the query, based on the sample input data (which we've also asked for). Cheers.

Comment: Expected result exported to excel and a picture attached to the original post. Thank you

Comment: It would be better pasted as text, since that's what it is. You're not showing us graphics :-). And we still don't have any sample input data so we can understand the derivation or attempt to run the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some time doing some additional research on this problem. One of my issues is that I have not had any training on this and as a result, the terminology is a severe area of weakness for me.

What I have been trying to do is to consolidate the queries down so that I can reduce the number of datasets. The resolution to my problem is as follows:

SELECT DISTINCT

(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EventId) FROM Transaction WHERE EventDate between DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0,DATEADD(YEAR,-1, @STARTDATE)), 0) AND DATEADD(Year,-1,@STARTDATE) AND Region IN (@Region)) A,

(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EventId) FROM Transaction WHERE EventDate between DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0,DATEADD(YEAR,-0, @STARTDATE)), 0) AND DATEADD(Year,-0,@STARTDATE) AND Region IN (@Region)) B

FROM Transaction

This does not contain all of the subqueries I need but should show you where I was going.